# Insert and populate two columns based on column wise conditions

Tags: r

I have this df:

```
data <- structure(list(location = c("bern", "bern", "zurich", "zurich", 
                                "basel", "basel", "basel"), location_latitude = c(4.1, 4.1, 6.2, 
                                                                                  6.2, 7.3, 7.3, 7.3), location_longitude = c(2.1, 2.1, 3.2, 3.2, 
                                                                                                                              5.6, 5.6, 5.6), location_population = c(38, 38, 72, 72, 46, 46, 
                                                                                                                                                                      46), origin = c("zurich", "basel", "bern", "basel", "bern", "zurich", 
                                                                                                                                                                                      "locarno"), origin_temperature = c(12, 20, 21, 20, 21, 12, 27
                                                                                                                                                                                      )), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

I have latitude and longitude for **location**, but I don’t have latitude and longitude for **origin**.

I want to insert two columns and populate them with latitude and longitude for **origin**, based on corresponding coordinates of column location, like this:

```
data_needed <- structure(list(location = c("bern", "bern", "zurich", "zurich", 
                                       "basel", "basel", "basel"), location_latitude = c(4.1, 4.1, 6.2, 
                                                                                         6.2, 7.3, 7.3, 7.3), location_longitude = c(2.1, 2.1, 3.2, 3.2, 
                                                                                                                                     5.6, 5.6, 5.6), location_population = c(38, 38, 72, 72, 46, 46, 
                                                                                                                                                                             46), origin = c("zurich", "basel", "bern", "basel", "bern", "zurich", 
                                                                                                                                                                                             "locarno"), origin_latitude = c("6.2", "7.3", "4.1", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "7.3", "4.1", "6.2", "NA"), origin_longitude = c("3.2", 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             "5.6", "2.1", "5.6", "2.1", "3.2", "NA"), origin_temperature = c(12, 
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              20, 21, 20, 21, 12, 27)), row.names = c(NA, 7L), class = "data.frame")
```

I assume it needs to be done column wise, but I don’t know how to do it.

Also I don’t want to have to add conditions that specify locations (e.g., if “zurich”), because the dataset has thousands of locations and origins. I need this to be done ‘automatically’.

Also note that origins that have no matching coordinates in locations (such as Locarno) should return NAs.

Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a way using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

data %>%
    select(origin = "location", origin_latitude = "location_latitude", origin_longitude = "location_longitude") %>%
    distinct() %>%
    left_join(data, ., by = "origin") %>%
    select(-origin_temperature, origin_temperature)

  location location_latitude location_longitude location_population  origin origin_latitude origin_longitude origin_temperature
1     bern               4.1                2.1                  38  zurich             6.2              3.2                 12
2     bern               4.1                2.1                  38   basel             7.3              5.6                 20
3   zurich               6.2                3.2                  72    bern             4.1              2.1                 21
4   zurich               6.2                3.2                  72   basel             7.3              5.6                 20
5    basel               7.3                5.6                  46    bern             4.1              2.1                 21
6    basel               7.3                5.6                  46  zurich             6.2              3.2                 12
7    basel               7.3                5.6                  46 locarno              NA               NA                 27
```

Comment: it worked, thank you so much. 2 quick questions so that I can understand the code: I gather that 'distinct()' retains unique rows, but why is this needed in this case? Also, what does '.,' do/mean when using 'left_join'?

Comment: We use `distinct` to prevent duplicate rows when we `join`. The `.` references the output of the current pipe, which we are `join`ing with our original `data`

Answer (score 3):

Using base R:

```
data <- within(data, origin_latitude <- location_latitude[match(origin, location)])
data <- within(data, origin_longitude<- location_longitude[match(origin, location)])
```

Using `data.table`:

```
setDT(data)
data[, 
     c("origin_latitude", "origin_longitude") := .SD[match(origin, location)], 
     .SDcols = c("location_latitude", "location_longitude")]
```

Comment: Many thanks for base R solution. Can you please explain how it works? In particular, the `match` function?

Comment: `match()` returns a vector of the positions of (first) matches of its first argument in its second. See for example `match(c("J", "O"), LETTERS)`. So `match(origin, location)` is asking, what is the first row where I can find this `origin` in the `location` column. And when we know the row we can find the corresponding lat/long.